# Razor and Ajax, how do I automatically update a single View?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Okay, so I have almost no experience in Ajax and I have been playing with razor and MVC for just a few days now, my question is, how would I update only a certain View instead of the whole Site?
I have a simple View called "Overview", my view uses

```
@{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}`
```

and I have a simple Controller, just returning Views

```
public ActionResult {
      return View();
}
```

so, lets imagine I have a database and theres a table where data is being added and I want to display the count of entries on my "Overview" Page refreshing every 5 seconds.

I have all the logic implemented on my "Overview"-View, how should I reload only the View instead of the whole HTML including `_Layout.cshtml`?

I have read a little bit about Ajax but it seems like mostly documents are loaded and written back as HTML, I just would like to get my View-Document being written back.

I have searched for similar questions and tried a lot but could'nt get it to work. Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: "t seems like mostly documents are loaded and written back as HTML, I just would like to get my View-Document being written back" What do you think your view is, if not HTML?

Comment: Anyway what you potentially want is either a) an MVC Partial View which returns the table, you can request an updated copy of that via ajax and insert it into the right place in your main view, or b) an MVC controller action which returns JSON and then you request that via ajax, and in the Javascript which runs when the request completes, you use that JSON to create some HTML (or render a HTML template) with which to update your main view's content. Both of these are common and sensible design patterns for this use case.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but this tutorial should really help get you where you want to be. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/302f8f/Asp-Net-mvc-using-jquery-ajax/